# collapsing toolbar title animation speed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have collapsing toolbar with nested scrollview, I want to change collapsing toolbar  title's animate(to toolbar) speed so my contents will not overlap when scrolling.

If I can make the animation fast my problem will be solved. It needs to go its new position(toolbar) quickly.

Please watch the video. 
https://youtu.be/8ewSpOYGpY0

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".testproject.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:minHeight="56dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="16dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="120dp"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="center|left"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:background="@color/lipstick">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="254dp"
                    android:background="@color/lipstick"


                    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:text="Good morning"
                        app:fontFamily="@font/akkuratprobold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:visibility="invisible"/>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/header_txt_2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:letterSpacing="-0.01"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                        android:text="Good morning text needs to animate to toolbar quickly so this text will not overlap"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
                <ImageView

                        android:layout_width="22dp"
                        android:layout_height="22dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wallet"
                        android:id="@+id/ic_wallet" android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/header_txt_3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="13sp"
                        android:text="£1,517.09    •    €100.00"
                        app:fontFamily="@font/akkuratprobold"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ic_wallet"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ic_wallet"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ic_wallet"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25" android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"/>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my workaround,

Collapsing toolbar title speed (collapsing toolbar to toolbar) related with your collapsing toolbar's height, so I put my contents out of an collapsing toolbar, top of nested scrollview, they look in same toolbar but actually they are not. 
So because collapsingtoolbar's height is low title animates quickly.